# Change Visibility of Divs from Code Behind (ASPX)

Tags: asp.net, html, visible

I have a table in html, and inside that table there are multiple rows 'tr',
inside each row there are multiple columns 'td'.

What I need it to change between two td's to show inside a particular row.

I have both of them specified in an aspx file, like the example below.

```
<div id="DirCaDiv1" runat="server" visible="false"> 
    <td class="heading4" align="left" style="width: 21%" id="DirAreaDiv_Text" runat="server" >
        &nbsp;Dir.Área:&nbsp;</td>
</div>


<div id="DirBaDiv1" runat="server" visible="false">
    <td class="heading4" align="left" style="width: 21%" id="DirCoordDiv_Text" runat="server" >
        &nbsp;Dir.Coord.:&nbsp;</td>
</div>
```

And in my aspx file I have a combo box event (combobox_changed) that change the visibility of each div.
It puts one DirCaDiv1.visible="false" and another one DirBaDiv1.Visible="true"

But I don't know why, it doesn't work, I change the item that is selected on the other combobox that is using the event,
and nothing happens...

Comment: When you set a breakpoint where you set visible to be true, do you hit the breakpoint?

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's because the visible property is a bool not a string so instead of using "true" or "false" use DirCaDiv1.Visible = true;

See also

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yes sorry thats what I meant, if I didn't do that it would give me error compilation, VS would warn me.
This is actually how I am doing inside a method of my code behind:

DirCaDiv1.Visible = false;
DirBaDiv1.Visible = true;

thanks alot for your reply ;)

Comment: So when you set the property when debugging what happens?

Comment: The combobox may not generate a post back so add an autopostback="true" to your combo box markup

Answer (score 1):

```
   <div runat="server" visible='<%# (Eval(condition)) ? true : false %>'></div>
```

that works for me

Answer (score 1):

Realizing this is a really **old** question...

*First*, the HTML is horribly broken, you can't have a `div` as a parent of a `td`.

*Second*, check the `OnPageLoad` event is not setting the combobox and therefore changing the selected value. Any initialization should take place inside `if(!IsPostback){/*Do Your Stuff here*/}`

I'm going to set the text of a literal control, this will ensure no additional HTML is rendered to the page. Note there are no `div` and only one `td`. This is a good thing! Alternatively you could just set the `innerText` or `innerHtml` of the TD directly

**ASPX**

```
<td class="heading4" align="left" style="width: 21%" id="DirLoc_Text" runat="server" >
    &nbsp;<asp:Literal runat="server" id="litLocText" />:&nbsp;
</td>
```

**C# Code Behind in the Combobox event handler**

```
litLocText.Text = comboBox.value == [your condition] ? "Dir.Área" : "Dir.Coord";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem, where I could not set a `div` element visible `(divSomeName.Visible=true;)`, which puzzled me for a while. Then, I found out that the reason why was in the parent element, which `Visible` property was set to `false`. I resolved my problem by moving the `div` element out of the invisible parent.